# H12SSL-i unable to install Proxmox

Tags: proxmox

I am trying to install latest Proxmox on my system with defaulted BIOS settings:

MB: Supermicro H12SSL-i
CPU: AMD Epyc 7742
GPU: NVIDIA RTX 3090
RAM: 512GB DDR4 RDIMM ECC

When I try to install the proxmox it always hangs on Loading initial ramdisk.. and the whole system freezes.

We already did a test of the ram for 12 hours and it passed without test.

Any idea what can be causing this issue ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can attempt to install Debian 12 (using Debian's suggestions to resolve any problems), and then convert it to Proxmox using [official instructions](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Install_Proxmox_VE_on_Debian_12_Bookworm). Don't forget to implement a supported partitioning scheme (e.g. LVM or ZFS must be present, though it's troublesome to install Debian on ZFS); in my experience, LVM over MD RAID works fine.